# Port forwarding in windows to device

Tags: networking, port, firewall, router, ethernet

Hi I'm trying to access remotely to the server of a device connected to Windows by `Ethernet` by port:80. I have already port forwarded that port to the PC and set the Firewall to allow access thru that port but I can't find a way to connect to the device from outside the network.

I was reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows and wondered if this could apply to my case:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=pc internal ip connectport=80 connectaddress=device pc_network ip
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your router has the port forwarding to reach windows server from the internet. You can use your router outside IP in canyouseeme.org to check this.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it has been set to the PC where the device (Siemens PLC) is connected with ports 80 and 443 forwarded. The PLC has its own IP address but as it isn't connected directly to the router, just by ethernet to the computer, I don't have the option to add the device, just the PC where it's connected.